# ggplot2: Change appearence of CI independent from mean in "mean_cl_boot"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot")` I want to make the line of the CI thicker, but keep the point (mean) small to keep small CIs visible.
Changing the size parameter affects the point and the line simultaneously.

Minimal example from the doc:

```
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg)) + geom_point()
d + stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", colour = "red", size = 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify another `geom`and add the `stat_summary` twice

```
d + stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", colour = "red", 
                 size = 2, geom = "linerange") + 
    stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_cl_boot", colour = "blue", 
                 size = 1.8, geom = "point", shape = 4)
```

[image]